# SQL Change Counter ON UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there are any way of changing a "counter" column after an update in the row.

So for example in this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE test
    (`ID` int, `Name` varchar (20), `Counter` int);


INSERT INTO test
    (`ID`, `Name`, `Counter`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Will', 0),
    (2, 'James', 0);
```

If I want to update the second result like this:

```
UPDATE test
SET Name = 'John'
WHERE id = 2
```

I want the counter to be changed to 1 as well. Is it something connected with the schema, like ON UPDATE something...? (I don not want to update the counter with the updating query)

Also if this is possible, is there are any way of setting the counter back to 0 after 10 days, or some period of time?

Comment: You might want to create a trigger, if the counter has to be set to 1 after a record gets updated.

Comment: I don't want just to be 1 after every update, I want to count the updates, so for example the next update after the counter is 1 will set the counter to 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a trigger:

```
CREATE trigger inc_counter
BEFORE UPDATE ON test
FOR EACH ROW
    SET new.Counter = new.Counter + 1
```

For the second part, resetting the counter after 10 days, you need an additional column:

```
last_updated TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Then you can have a periodic task that does:

```
UPDATE test
SET counter = -1
WHERE last_updated < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY);
```

You need to set it to `-1` here because the trigger adds 1 during the update.

Comment: that works perfect! Thanks a lot. For the second part do you have any suggestion (the part where the counter is reset after a period of time) ? Many thanks again.

Comment: Added that to the answer